# Spring + JavaScript

Tags: spring-mvc

Tenho um form JSP, no qual embuti Javascript, e uma vez que faço as validações do lado do cliente, criei uma função javaScript “salvar(param)”.
Ao clicar no botão salvar, é invocada função javaScript “salvar(param)” que por sua vez primeiro invoca a função que valída os dados do objecto a ser salvo atravéz do método "validar()" e por último aciona o metódo da controller (save()) que faz o save do tal objecto.

O bug que está ocorrer, é que uma vez que este método `save()` da controller, recebe o objecto a ser salvo como parâmetro, ao acionar este mesmo método via javaScrip(salvar(param), Nota param=Objecto a ser salvo), o param chega na controller vazio, ou seja como objecto nulo.

Tambem tentei capturar este objecto a ser salvo, usando um instâcia do `HttpServletRequest`, da seguinte maneira:

```
tipopagamento = (TipoPagamentoVO) request.getSession().getAttribute(“tipopagamento”);
```

Mas na mesma o objecto chega nullo, mesmo tendo passado na validação.

Não estou entendendo porquê o objecto está chegando lá no metódo save() da minha da minha controller (TipoPagamentoAction) como null

**Meu Form JSP:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function salvar(tipopagamento) {

    if (!validar()) return;

    $.post("tipopagamento/save?tipopagamento="+tipopagamento);
}



function validar(){

    if (document.getElementById('designacao').value == ''){
        alert("O campo 'Designacao' deve ser preenchido");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('descricao').value == ''){
        alert("O campo 'Descricao' deve ser preenchido");
        return false;
    }                            

    return true;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="/sigra/tipopagamento/save" name="tipopagamentoForm"  modelAttribute="tipopagamento" > 


        <fieldset>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>${statusMessage}</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <fieldset>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%">
                                        <label> Designa&ccedil;&atilde;o</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="85">
                                        <span id="refresh_01">              
                                            <input type="text" id="designacao" name="designacao" style=" width: 100%" value="${tipopagamento.designacao}" >
                                        </span>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%">
                                        <label>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="85">
                                        <span id="refresh_02">
                                            <textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" rows="5" cols="40" style="width: 100%" >${tipopagamento.descricao}</textarea>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <fieldset>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                <!--  <a id="save"  href="/sigra/tipopagamento/save.html" onclick="testFunction()">teste</a> -->    
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" id="sa" value="Salvar" onclick="salvar(${tipopagamento});">    
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="abc">
                                        <input type="button" value="Limpar" onclick="limpar();">    
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" value="Cancelar" onclick="testFunction();">    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
</body>
```

**TipoPagamentoVO()**

package iim.sigra.model.parametrizacao.tipopagamento;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TIPOPAGAMENTO")
public class TipoPagamentoVO {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
protected long selfId;

@NotNull
protected String designacao;
protected String descricao;


public TipoPagamentoVO() {

}

public TipoPagamentoVO(HttpServletRequest rq) {

    }


public TipoPagamentoVO(long SelfId, String designacao, String descricao){

    this.selfId = 0;
    this.designacao = designacao;
    this.descricao = descricao;

}

public long getSelfId() {
    return selfId;
}

public void setSelfId(long selfId) {
    this.selfId = selfId;
}

public String getDesignacao() {
    return designacao;
}

public void setDesignacao(String designacao) {
    this.designacao = designacao;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {

    TipoPagamentoVO tipo = (TipoPagamentoVO) object;

    return (this.selfId==tipo.selfId && tipo.selfId!=0) || (this.designacao!=null && this.designacao.equalsIgnoreCase(tipo.designacao));
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "SelfId: "+this.selfId +","+" Designação: "+this.designacao +","+" Descrição: "+this.descricao;
}
```

}

**Minha Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/tipopagamento"})
public class TipoPagamentoAction {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listAllPagamentos(){

    ArrayList<TipoPagamentoVO> allTipoPagamentos = new ArrayList<TipoPagamentoVO>();
    TipoPagamentoDAO dao = new TipoPagamentoDAO();

    allTipoPagamentos = dao.getAll();

    return new ModelAndView("/tipopagamento/tipopagamento", "allTipoPagamentos", allTipoPagamentos);
}


@RequestMapping(value="/save", method= {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public  ModelAndView save(TipoPagamentoVO tipopagamento , UsuarioVO user, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{



    //  tipopagamento = (TipoPagamentoVO) request.getSession().getAttribute("tipopagamento");


    TipoPagamentoDAO dao = new TipoPagamentoDAO();
    ArrayList<TipoPagamentoVO> allTipoPagamentos = new ArrayList<TipoPagamentoVO>();

    dao.save(tipopagamento, user);
    allTipoPagamentos = dao.getAll();

    return new ModelAndView("/tipopagamento/tipopagamento", "allTipoPagamentos", allTipoPagamentos);
}
```

}

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código da classe `TipoPagamentoVO`, por favor.

Comment: Viva @Felipe Marinho! Tudo bem? Editei a minha questão, não sei se agora está mais claro, o facto é que o objecto a ser salvo está a chegar na minha action como null e assim ñ pode ser salvo. Muito obrigado pela atenção. Por favor peço a sua ajuda

Answer (score 0):

A *expression language* é processada do lado do servidor. No trecho abaixo, quando você utiliza a expressão `${tipopagamento}`, o servidor vai evocar o método `toString` da classe e passar como argumento para o método salvar. Dessa forma, o seu método salvar vai sempre utilizar o parâmetro que você estipulou no servidor, e nunca vai pegar os parâmetros dos *inputs*.

```
<input type="button" id="sa" value="Salvar" onclick="salvar(${tipopagamento});">
```

Na sua requisição *POST*:

```
$.post("tipopagamento/save?tipopagamento="+tipopagamento);
```

O valor do `tipopagamento` é enviado como um parâmetro do método *GET* no formato do `toString`. Seu controlador acaba não sabendo o que fazer.

Como, aparentemente, você faz um redirecionamento da página no seu controlador, não há necessidade da chamada ser assíncrona (`$.post`). Você poderia simplesmente usar o *input type submit* para enviar os dados e utilizar o jQuery para interceptar o envio e validar as informações. Exemplo:

#### Script

```
<head>  
    <!-- Resto do que você tem no seu head -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >

        function validar(){
            if (document.getElementById('designacao').value === ''){
                alert("O campo 'Designacao' deve ser preenchido");
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('descricao').value === ''){
                alert("O campo 'Descricao' deve ser preenchido");
                return false;
            }                            
            return true;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tipoPagamentoForm").submit(function(e) {
                if(!validar()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });             
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

#### Formulário

```
<form id="tipoPagamentoForm" action="/sigra/tipopagamento/save" method="POST">
    <label for="designacao">Designação:</label>
    <input type="text" id="designacao" name="designacao" style=" width: 100px" value="${tipopagamento.designacao}" >
    <br />

    <label for="descricao">Descrição:</label>
    <textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" style="width: 100px" >${tipopagamento.descricao}</textarea>
    <br />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Filipe Marinho muito obrgado do fundo do coração. A sua correção foi uma espécie de divisor de águas. o facto é que sou novo no Spring e quase que nunca mexi com JQuery, por esse motivo acabo cometendo erros elementares. Agora depois da sua dica estou avançado, Que Deus lhe conceda mais conhecimento e disposição para partilhar esse mesmo conhecimento.

Comment: muito obrgado do fundo do coração. A sua correção foi uma espécie de divisor de águas. o facto é que sou novo no Spring e quase que nunca mexi com JQuery, por esse motivo acabo cometendo erros elementares. Agora depois da sua dica estou avançado, Que Deus lhe conceda mais conhecimento e disposição para partilhar esse mesmo conhecimento.

Comment: pedia uma dica: Se eu já tenho um objecto TipoPagamentoVO gravado na BD e consigo fazer retrieve para carrega-lo no form, precisando eu de editar esse mesmo objecto como faria para passa-lo como parametro, pois na minha controller tenho um método "actualizar (TipopagamentoVO tipopagamento)", Consigo facilmente mandar objectos do controller para o form, mas a minha dificuldade é de buscar o objecto do form para o controller. cmprmntos!

Comment: @gtamele Basta você colocar nas propriedades `name` das tags `input` o nome do atributo correspondente da sua classe. Dessa forma, o Spring vai popular os campos do seu objeto com os valores do formulário quando enviado. Como se trata de uma atualização, você deve ter no seu formulário o o identificador do objeto (no caso `selfId`). Caso você não queira que o usuário veja o identificador, você pode colocá-lo em um `input type="hidden"`, exemplo: `<input type="hidden" name="selfId" value="${tipopagamento.selfId}">`.

Comment: ! Viva Ilustre, muito obrgado pela sua paciência. Apenas para esclarecer k eu faço CRUD do Objecto no mesmo formulário, e tenho um botão p salvar: <input type="submit" value="Salvar" >, qdo eu faço o save, o objecto chega ao controller c/ dados e o Spring popula os campos do Obejcto. Tenho um outro botão no mesmo formulário p Actualizar o Objecto:<input type="button" value="Actualizar" onclick="actualizar();">. Ao clicar neste botão é invocado um método Javascript k faz a validação e por último acciona o metódo actualizar(TipoPagamentoVO tipopagamento). O berro é k ...

Comment: !..O Berro é k o objecto tipopagamento chega ao controller vazio. Assim gostava de saber como proceder p assegurar k o objecto chegue populado com os dados dos campos do formulário? Peço uma vez mais a sua Intervenção

Comment: ! Outro aspecto, confoorme dizia que uso o mesmo formulário, assim em relação ao campo <input type="hidden" name="selfId" value="${tipopagamento.selfId}"> qdo a operação é save, surge um bug: Field error in object 'tipoPagamentoVO' on field 'selfId': rejected value [];. Como contornar este erro?

Comment: @gtamele Não sei como você está fazendo a requisição para atualizar o objeto,  mas suponho que seja através do jQuery. Se isso for verdade, o problema deve ser causado pela forma que você está enviando os dados. Quando você faz uma requisição POST pelo jQuery, os parâmetros devem ser atribuídos a uma variável chamada `data`. Para obter os dados do formulário, você precisa pegar o formulário pelo `id` e utilizar o método `serialize`. Dê uma olhada [nesse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25881249) e o utilize como um modelo.

Comment: @gtamele Sobre o erro na hora de salvar: o `id` só deve ser enviado na atualização. Como o identificador da sua classe é gerado de forma automática, ele não pode estar preenchido na hora de persistir o objeto. Talvez seja mais simples criar páginas distintas para criar e para atualizar.

Comment: Viva  @Felipe Marinho! Eu estava a fazer da seguinte forma, minha jsp:      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" >

Comment: Viva @Felipe Marinho! Eu estava a fazer da seguinte forma, minha jsp:<script>
  function actualizar(tipopagamento){
   if (!validar()) {return;}
   $.post("actualizar", {'tipopagamento': tipopagamento});
  }
    </script>

<body>
 <input type="button" id="Actualizar" value="Actualizar" onclick="actualizar(${tipopagamento});" > 
</body>

Comment: Assim como deste jeito, segundo a sua recomendação,ñ sei o que 
pode estar de errado assim pork o botão não acusa acção:

<head>  
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
  $("#Actualizar").click(function(){   
   $.post("actualizar.html", $("#tipoPagamentoForm").serialize(), function(data) {
         alert(data);
     });
 });
 </script></head>
<body>
 <!-- Coisas-->
 <input type="button" id="Actualizar" value="Actualizar" > 
 <!-- Coisas-->
</body>

Comment: Do lado do Controller:

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/tipopagamento"})
public class TipoPagamentoAction {

 @RequestMapping(value="/actualizar", method= {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
 public String actualizar(TipoPagamentoVO tipopagamento, UsuarioVO user) throws Exception{
  
  
  TipoPagamentoDAO dao = new TipoPagamentoDAO();
  
  dao.update(tipopagamento, user);
  
  return "redirect:";
 }
}